# How to retrieve userID from table

Tags: html, mysql, database, servlets

I have a table named 'User' and it has an autoincremented field `userID`.

I want to retrieve that `userID` in my servlet. There is no such parameter/field referred to on that respective HTML. How can I use that `userID` in my servlet?

Comment: Do you mean last_insert_id? Your insert should return this in some way. Your question is really cryptic since you do not show what you have tried and how you insert and how you want to retrieve. It sounds like "oculd you write the program for me?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your question is far to broad for a definite answer mate but here goes my best guess.

I assume you run this table and data in mysql since you tagged this as mysql.
you can retrieve the data you wish with the query as below:

```
SELECT userID FROM User;
```

Note: If you have more than 1 this will return all of them. If you want to limit this down to 1 you will need to match that to another unique parameter in your table. For example lets say you have a column in User table called "telephone"

the query would be:

```
SELECT userID FROM User WHERE telephone = '1234567890';
```

You can then display the result in your html, depending on what language you use to execute this query with.

Hope this helps